# Symfony: load config by subdomain

Tags: php, configuration, symfony

How can I load custom config for subdomain in Symfony 3, for ex:
**red.color.net:**

```
    -ColorBundle
    --Resources
    ---config
    ----red.yml
    ----green.yml
    ----blue.yml
```

**blue.color.net:**

```
    -ColorBundle
    --Resources
    ---config
    ----red.yml
    ----green.yml
    ----blue.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

In file

> app/AppKernel.php

You have a method

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

You can modify its body to load any configuration file you need

Comment: I was reading a symfony source code and solution will be little bit more complex. Configuration is built before request handling. I'll try to prepare an example